# Socket.io's path adds slash at the end of path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io

I am encountering the following error on the frontend when trying to connect to a socket provided by the client.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain:1255/getTxInfo/?txId=123&secret=123=4&transport=websocket' failed:
```

My configuration is the following:

```
  var socket = io('https://domain:1255', {
    path: '/getTxInfo',
    transports: ['websocket'],
    autoconnect: true,
    query: {
      txId: this.tx.txid,
      secret: this.tx.secret
    }
  });
```

I presume my problem is caused by the fact that Socket.io is adding a "/" between the path and the query parameters.

```
.../getTxInfo / ?txId=1....
```

Is it possible to get rid of the slash through socket.io configuration?

Comment: Have you found a fix for this? I have the same issue using `socket.io` & `react`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's late, but to fix this issue you have to set the optional property `addTrailingSlash` to `false`:

```
const socket = io("wss://localhost:4000", 
{  
  path: "/my/path",
  addTrailingSlash: false,
  query:{
    id_example: "1"
  },
  transports: ["websocket"], 
});
```